# Wiping Free Space

Tags: luks

I learnt through the web that LUKS does not encrypt free space on a disk. While installing LUbuntu and setting up LUKS I did not select the option to wipe free space on my disk.Is there any way to do it afterwards without any loss of data on the same disk? The disk in question is the only partition storing /boot etc and the filesystem.I use LUbuntu 18.04.

Comment: I've done it before by creating a big_file that justs used the free space & filled the disk with a pattern or zero's (I wasn't using LUKS  or encryption but I doubt it'd make a difference).  I've done it a few times, with perl script or `dd`.  Then erase the created 'big_file' to free the space again.  *I won't provide `dd` command as I don't have time to test, or doubt I'd have saved how it was done before*

Comment: Easy CLI tool to wipe free space : zerofree. See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/zerofree.8.html